# Triangulation in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, loops

Is there a smart way to produce the following diagram using tikz?

[image]

With smart I mean not drawing each line for line and node for node but rather something like a for loop.

Comment: Some use of `\foreach` probably, or maybe `\matrix`.  Are you wishing to recreate the labelling - if so could you explain how it's derived as it seems pretty non-trivial (no d but multiple repeated letters, I can't get my head round it).

Comment: Please provide the non-smart code you've got so people don't have to start from scratch in order to help you.

Comment: @DaiBowen, the letters should be like that to produce a triangulation for  a torus.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Example, which uses both smart stuff (`grid`), `\foreach` loops and manual elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
    (0, 0) grid[step=1cm] (3, 3)
    (0, 2) -- (1, 3)
    (0, 1) -- (2, 3)
    (0, 0) -- (3, 3)
    (1, 0) -- (3, 2)
    (2, 0) -- (3, 1)
  ;
  \fill[radius=3pt]
    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 3} {
      \foreach \y in {0, ..., 3} {
        (\x, \y) circle[]
      }
    }
  ;
  \path[above left]
    \foreach \y in {0, 3} {
      \foreach[count=\x] \v in {a, b, c, a} {
        (\x - 1, \y) node {$\v$}
      }
    }
    \foreach \p/\v in {
      {0, 2}/e,
      {1, 2}/f,
      {2, 2}/g,
      {3, 2}/e,
      {0, 1}/h,
      {1, 1}/j,
      {2, 1}/k,
      {3, 1}/h%
    } {
      (\p) node {$\v$}
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Ow, thanks. I didn' t know about `circle[]`. I have been using `circle ()` to inform radius.

Comment: `circle(<radius>)` is the old syntax. The documentation says, that "the use of parentheses for something other than a coordinate is ill-chosen." Therefore, I am using the new and normal syntax with square brackets.

Answer (score 13):

A (hopefully accurate) scalable version for arbitrary size (can't say if it's mathematically useful but was fun to make).

[`alphalph`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) used to generate arbitrary number of labels some increased spacing is probably necessary if you're going beyond a 5x5 grid to make more space for the double letter labels.  The code basically uses a lot of `foreach` with a little bit of maths to make sure each label has the appropriate number associated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\newcommand{\triangulation}[1]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\triangulationdimension}{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\triangulationdim}{\triangulationdimension-1}
\begin{scope}[yscale=-1]
\node [circle,draw,fill=black,label=above left:{\alphalph{1}}] at (\triangulationdimension,\triangulationdimension) {};
\foreach \i  [evaluate=\i as \l  using int(\triangulationdimension*(\i-1)+1)] in {1,...,\triangulationdim} {
    \node [circle,draw,fill=black,label=above left:{\alphalph{\i}}] at (\i,\triangulationdimension) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=black,label=above left:{\alphalph{\l}}] at (\triangulationdimension,\i) {};
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \k  using int(\triangulationdimension*(\j-1)+\i)] in {1,...,\triangulationdim} {
        \node [circle,draw,fill=black,label=above left:{\alphalph{\k}}] at (\i,\j) {};
        \foreach \x in {0,1} {
            \draw (\i+\x,\j) -- (\i+\x,\j+1);
            \draw (\j,\i+\x) -- (\j+1,\i+\x);
        }
        \draw (\j,\i+1) -- (\j+1,\i);
    }
}
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \triangulation{3}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \triangulation{4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \triangulation{8}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A sort of a programmer styled answer, similar to @HeikoOberdiek 's one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \x in {0,..., 3}{
        \foreach \y in {0,..., 3}{
            \fill (\x, \y) circle (3pt);
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (\x,\y);
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 2}{
            \foreach \y in {2, ..., 0}{
                \draw (\x, \y) -- (\x + 1, \y + 1);
            }
    }
    \path[above left]
        \foreach \a in {0, 3}{
            \foreach[count=\x] \b in {a, b, c, a}{
                (\x - 1, \a) node {$\b$}
            }
        }
        \foreach \a/\b in {
            {0, 2}/e,
            {1, 2}/f,
            {2, 2}/g,
            {3, 2}/e,
            {0, 1}/h,
            {1, 1}/j,
            {2, 1}/k,
            {3, 1}/h
        } {
        (\a) node {$\b$}
        }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), using the [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) interface.  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

The MP construct `forsuffixes` provides a way to use the labels to control the loop.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    numeric u;   u = 1.618cm;
    numeric x,y; x = 0; y = 0; 

    forsuffixes @=a,b,c,a,
                  h,j,k,h,
                  e,f,g,e,
                  a,b,c,a:

       if (x>0):           draw ((x,y) -- (x-u,y  )); fi
       if (y>0):           draw ((x,y) -- (x,  y-u)); fi
       if (x>0) and (y>0): draw ((x,y) -- (x-u,y-u)); fi

       dotlabel.ulft("$" & str @ & "$", (x,y));

       x := x + u;
       if x > 3u:
          x := 0;
          y := y + u;
       fi

    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```